# Find corresponding fourth-order DE for family solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem is as follows. (I'm paraphrasing, since the original is in Chinese.)

> Consider the following family of curves: $y = c_1e^x + c_2e^{2x} +
> c_3e^{3x} + c_4x$
>
> Find the corresponding fourth-order differential equation. Tip: you
>   can first find the third order, and then use the escalation method.

I've tried some common methods for elimination of arbitrary coefficients, but I always run into problems with the $c_4x$ term. (Most things I've found have to do with using *reduction of order* to find a second solution for a higher-order DE, rather than working the other way around from the general solution.)

How can I find the corresponding DE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The successive derivations lead to the linear relmationships between $y'',y''',y''''$ and $c_1e^x,c_2e^{2x},c_3e^{3x}$.

One can solve then for $c_1e^x,c_2e^{2x},c_3e^{3x}$ as functions of $y'',y''',y''''$.

Then, putting them into the equation of $y$ and $y'$ allows to eliminate all parameters $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$.

Finally, the relationship between the $y,y',y'',y''',y''''$ is obtained, which is the expected differential equation.

This boring task is made easier thanks to matrix calculus :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! This looks about right to me; I'll go through it in detail and accept your answer tomorrow. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Of course, anyone can make mistake. So, it's better to check it carefully. In any case this gives the method.

Comment: This was a very elegant way to solve the problem. Thank you again!

Comment: @JJacquelin Equation is equivalent to
$Determinant(Wronskian(x,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x},y(x)))=0$.